# AngularJs $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); for remove Hash to URL not work

Tags: angularjs, routes

I have a problem with the function $ locationProvider.html5Mode (true), this is the setting:

```
var app = angular.module("app", [
"ngRoute",
"ngAnimate"
]);


// ROUTE CONFIG
app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

$routeProvider.
    when("/archive", {
      templateUrl: "archive.php",
      controller: "archiveCtrl",
      animate: "slide-left"
    }).
    when("/single", {
      templateUrl: "single.php",
      controller: "singleCtrl",
      animate: "slide-left"
    }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: "/archive"
    });

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

});
```

In the head tag:

```
<head>
    <base href="/">
</head>
```

The root of the site is

```
site.com/main.php
```

Where main.php contains the div ng-view

Any idea why it does not work?

Answer (score 0):

here is a working example I created on JSFiddle, I removed the templateUrl and use template instead, but it shouldn't matter in this case(you are asking how does html5mode and base work)

## html

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <a href="/single">single</a>
  <a href="/archive">archive</a>
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

## Javascript

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", [
    "ngRoute"
  ])
  .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when("/archive", {
        template: "<p>archive</p>"
      })
      .when("/single", {
        template: "<p>single</p>"
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/archive"
      });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  }])
  .controller("mainCtrl", function mainCtrl($scope, $location) {
    $scope.$location = $location;
  });
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzlstc415/ku7xpfu7/)

Comment: why it is in the css file? </style><base href="/"><style>

Comment: this is just a JSfiddle hack because they dont allow to change head, it is same as put it in head in your local index.html file. You can inspect the result on JSfiddle, and you will see the <base> get added to normal head

Comment: Thanks Its working But its not work in when i page refresh any solution for it

Comment: I don't know the setup of you project , therefore I m not 100% sure what is causing the problem. However most probably it is because you directly opened the index.html in browser or serving the project with out serving index.html for all URL. When you type /foo/bar in URL, the browser is actually searching for a file named bar under foo folder in you project folder. To make the the dynamic route work with URL u need to serve index.html for any given url

Comment: If you are using express.js to serve. Do something like this: app = express();
// your normal configuration like `app.use(express.bodyParser());` here
// ...
app.use(app.router);
app.use(function(req, res) {
  // Use res.sendfile, as it streams instead of reading the file into memory.
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});